# I think someone may have just downvoted a whole bunch of [unity3d] tagged questions

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, downvotes

I submitted a question that was later downvoted without comment, and then when I clicked over to the list of other [unity3d] tagged questions a whole bunch of them from the list had also been downvoted. Something seems a bit fishy here. Could this be a person or an automated glitch at work? Thanks!

Comment: Just to be clear, you noticed because they were mostly your questions?

Comment: @Machavity No, only one of them was mine. I noticed because I watch the [unity3d] tag

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't anything surprising about a bunch of questions in a tab meriting downvotes.

Comment: I just looked at half a dozen & they mostly merited downvotes per the [help].

Comment: I always like these questions, that ALWAYS seem to skip the very important 'are these questions deserving of upvotes in the first place'

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> I submitted a question that was later downvoted without comment…

This is normal. Comments should *never* accompany votes, whether up or down. [There is no obligation or expectation *whatsoever* to leave a comment when you downvote](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin), and if you *do* choose to leave a comment suggesting possible improvements, you should not reveal how you voted.

> …when I clicked over to the list of other [unity3d] tagged questions a whole bunch of them from the list had also been downvoted. Something seems a bit fishy here.

There's nothing particularly fishy about this.

Unfortunately, a large majority of the questions that Stack Overflow gets do not meet [our standards](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and can justifiably be downvoted. Furthermore, there are no "rules" surrounding which posts are eligible for a downvote—as long as users are not engaging in vote fraud, they can cast their votes however they personally see fit.

I took a quick look at [the newest questions with the [unity3d] tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unity3d), and, by my judgment, easily 50–60% of the last 10 are calling out for downvotes. Questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61981273/i-want-to-know-the-name-of-that-sorting-algorithm), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61981653/what-is-this-error-in-unity-loading-assembly-failed-assets-plugins-mono-data), and [definitely this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61979335/como-posso-obter-o-ip-no-webgl-do-unity) are all of *severely* low quality—so bad that they not only needed downvoting, but also closing. Many other recent questions with this tag are problematic to a slightly lesser extent.

> Could this be a person or an automated glitch at work?

Probably a person. Definitely not an automated glitch. There are almost no automated downvotes<sup>*</sup>.

---

<sup>*</sup> <sub>The only exceptions are spam/abusive flags, which, when raised, cast an automatic downvote against the post. However, all of these such flags are reviewed by moderators, and if the flag is not validated, the automatic downvote against the post is removed. Furthermore, if someone is abusing the flag (i.e., casting a large number of false positive flags), causing posts to be temporarily downvoted, then moderators will notice this abuse and reach out to the user. We have not noticed any such abuse related to [unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) questions or any other tags.</sub>